# How can CSS transition be used to increase Bootstrap card font size on hover?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I simply want to increase the size of the text inside a bootstrap `card` class and change its color on `hover` action but my code only changes the color and does not increase the font size neither does any transition happen. I am not an expert frontend dev so pardon me if you spot my mistake and point it out. Here's the code I am working with

CSS

```
#team .card {
  border: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;

  transition: font 1s ease-in-out;
}

#team .card:hover {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: white;
}
```

html

```
<div class="card bg-dark shadow">
    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
        <h6 class="font-weight-normal">
            foo bar 
        </h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

How should I go about the transition?

Comment: check out working sample of your code https://jsfiddle.net/3huv958b/1/

Comment: Where's the element with the ID of team in your example?

Answer (score 1):

The font size is governed by H6 tag, so adding it to the css will solve it

```
#team .card {
  border: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;

  transition: font 1s ease-in-out;
}

#team .card:hover h6 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :)

```css
#team .card {
  border: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1rem;

  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#team .card:hover {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="team">
<div class="card bg-dark shadow">
    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
        <h6 class="font-weight-normal">
            foo bar 
        </h6>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about an actual explanation instead of just 'Here you go :)'?

Comment: yup man sorry, need to remove #team id name that you have been mentioned in css

Comment: Why have you taken out the id `#team`? What happens if I want to target only certain divs with `card` class when there are more than one div with the `card` class?

Comment: then you need to set a new div that contains #team before this one ( <div class="card bg-dark shadow"> )

Comment: I actually do have a div before that one with the `#team` id. So the divs with the `card` class I am targeting are right inside the `#team` div. With your code, the `h6` text color is animated but the size stays the same.

Comment: really the size stays the same.

Comment: yes it does. I will look over it again and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Update below part in CSS.

```
.card:hover .font-weight-normal{
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: white;
}
```